# How can I associate file types to a C app in macOS?

Tags: c, macos

I'm writing a C application and I want to be able to open CSV files in MacOS with it by clicking on the file.

**Here's what I've done so far:**

I wrote the C application. The path to the CSV file can be passed as an `*argv[]` argument and that gets processed inside the main function. I put the build executable into an .app folder under `myapp.app/Contents/MacOS`. I also created an `Info.plist` file under `myapp.app/Contents` specifying the support for csv-files. I now can select my application as default to open csv-files. However, the file is not opened. Instead, I get this message:

> The Document <document_name> can not be opened. <app_name> cannot open files in the "comma-separated value" format.

**The problem:**
seems like I need to implement some kind of [`application(_:openFiles:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplicationdelegate/1428742-application) function. However, all the examples I could find are referring to Objective-C, while I'm writing a plain C application.

Is there a way to associate document types to a plain C application in macOS, or is there any other way to map the open type extensions to the argv arguments inside an .app application?

---

My Info.plist file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
      <array>
    <string>csv</string>
      </array>
      <key>LSIsAppleDefaultForType</key>
      <string>Yes</string>
      <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
      <string>Editor</string>
      <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
      <string>comma-separated value</string>
    </dict>
  </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Do any of the techniques in the answers to ["Creating a windowed application in pure C on MacOS"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269329/creating-a-windowed-application-in-pure-c-on-macos) help?